# SharePoint online - Retreive all list items from multiple list matching to a content type

Tags: content-type, csom, online

Site contents - Multiple lists tagged with particular content type "CT1". The lists are dynamically created based on business requirements to will keep on adding in the site contents.

Requirements: Pull all the matching items from all the lists with content type = 'CT1' & assigned to = current user.

Environment : SharePoint online

Can anyone help me with the CAML query or any approach to show the data based on above mentioned requirement.

Comment: are you using C# CSOM ? is it ok to use search rest api or you need real time info ?

Comment: csom would be preferable .. if nothing works then will go for search rest api

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using REST. Below is the endpoint for REST

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:ContentTypeName'
```

And you can also achieve this using Content Query Webpart. Below is the link to support.office.com documentation on this:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-d560f477-8fc1-4258-aeb2-70aa932e07da

Comment: Content query webpart can show only few fields ... i need to show data in tabular format , list list view

Comment: You can try modifying ItemStyle.xsl to format the data. I have modified it in on prem though not sure about online.

Comment: let me try ... if that work it would be great.